# Problem adding Flutter DIalogflow and Firebase Storage to dependencies

Tags: firebase, flutter, dialogflow-es

I am trying to add flutter_dialogflow and firebase_storage to my dependencies for a flutter project. But when ever I try to add a recent version of firebase storage to pubspec.yaml file it gives me this error

***Because no versions of flutter_dialogflow match >0.1.3 <0.2.0 and flutter_dialogflow 0.1.3 depends on http ^0.12.0+2, flutter_dialogflow ^0.1.3 requires http ^0.12.0+2.
And because firebase_storage_web >=1.0.0 depends on http ^0.13.0, flutter_dialogflow ^0.1.3 is incompatible with firebase_storage_web >=1.0.0.
Because firebase_storage >=10.2.9 <10.2.10 depends on firebase_storage_web ^3.2.10 and firebase_storage >=10.2.10 depends on firebase_storage_web ^3.2.11, firebase_storage >=10.2.9 requires firebase_storage_web ^3.2.10.
Thus, flutter_dialogflow ^0.1.3 is incompatible with firebase_storage >=10.2.9.
So, because flutterbotv2 depends on both flutter_dialogflow ^0.1.3 and firebase_storage ^10.2.9, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because flutterbotv2 depends on both flutter_dialogflow ^0.1.3 and firebase_storage ^10.2.9, version solving failed.)***

To resolve this I had to add a very old version of firebase storage which also gave me this error when I ran pub get in the pubspec.yaml file

***The plugin `firebase_storage` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding: https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.***

Please does anyone know a way around this problem because I really need both dependencies for a project I'm working on.
This are my dependencies in the pubspec.yaml file

```
    dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter
      cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
      flutter_dialogflow: ^0.1.3
      hexcolor: ^2.0.6
      eva_icons_flutter: ^3.1.0
      firebase_core: ^1.14.0
      firebase_storage: ^0.3.2
```

Comment: You appear to be using a very old version of `firebase_storage`.  The version I'm using is `firebase_storage: ^10.2.10`.  Perhaps that's the problem?

Comment: Yes i am aware of that but if I try using a newer version it gives me the first error i provided in bold italics in my question because of the flutter_dialogflow dependency and i really need that in this project I'm working on as well as the firebase_storage dependency but they appear to be incompatible @JonMountjoy

Comment: It's a little hacky, but I think you can try and override that dependency. ie. add something like this to your `pubspec.yaml`: 

```
dependency_overrides:
  http: ^0.13.0
```